# WordPress redirect redirecting too many times or not at all

Tags: php, functions, hooks, redirect, actions

I am new to WordPress. I am trying to simply redirect users to a login page if they go to the account page without being logged in.

I first tried adding this code to the functions.php code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_if_user_not_logged_in' );

function redirect_if_user_not_logged_in() && is_page('example.com/account') {
    
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        
        wp_redirect( 'example.com/login' ); 
        
        exit;
    }
}
```

This ultimately resulted in nothing. At all happening. I tried the hook 'admin_init' as well which made no difference.

I tried removing the conditional statement about the current page and changed the code to simply:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_if_user_not_logged_in' );

function redirect_if_user_not_logged_in() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        
        wp_redirect( 'example.com/login' ); 
        
        exit;
    }
}
```

This resulted in the "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error on both Chrome and Microsoft Edge. I would've thought that this would just redirect once but it appears that it gets caught in a loop.

Again, I tried this with several different hooks as well as 'init' and 'admin_init'.

The code is located just below the <?php of functions.php.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. Perhaps I am putting this code in the wrong file or I need to adjust the add_action and hook or use remove_action somewhere else. Please lend me a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

> I am trying to simply redirect users to a login page if they go to the
> account page without being logged in.

Try with `is_page()` once again, **but use the correct syntax**: (see [`home_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/) for more information about the function, but it's an easy way to get your WordPress URL and you can pass any valid path like `/login/`)

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_if_user_not_logged_in' );

function redirect_if_user_not_logged_in() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'account' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/login/' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

---

### More Details

> I first tried adding this code to the functions.php

Well, if your function actually starts like so (note the `&& is_page` part), then that's a (PHP) syntax error..

```php
function redirect_if_user_not_logged_in() && is_page('example.com/account') {
```

Secondly, you've incorrectly used [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/): `is_page('example.com/account')` — if you want to check if the *main WordPress query* (which runs automatically on page load) is for a Page (post type `page`) with a specific *slug* (that's used in the permalink) like `account`, then the correct syntax is:

```php
is_page( 'account' )
// pass just the Page slug; don't include the "example.com/"
```

which returns true if the current page URL is like `https://example.com/account/` and that your WordPress URL is `https://example.com/` (with or without the slash).

> Again, I tried this with several different hooks as well as 'init' and
> 'admin_init'.

[`admin_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_init/) runs only on the admin side, i.e. `wp-admin`, so you would *not* want to use that hook for what you're trying to do.

[`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) would work if you just wanted to redirect *without* checking whether you are on a specific Page.

Otherwise, you should use a *later hook* which runs after WordPress finished parsing the current URL and setup the main query.

So for example, you could (and most devs, including myself, would also) use the [`template_redirect` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/), like you originally tried with.

> This resulted in the "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error on both Chrome and
> Microsoft Edge. I would've thought that this would just redirect once
> but it appears that it gets caught in a loop.

Yes, because the hook runs on every page load/request, and because you only checked if the current user is logged-in, then as long as the user is *not* (yet) logged-in, then the redirect will happen on each page request. It can be illustrated like so:

1. I visited your account page at example.com/account
2. The `template_redirect` hook ran and your code checked if I was logged-in to your site
3. If was not and thus your code redirected me to example.com/login
4. On the login page, the `template_redirect` hook ran and your code checked if I was logged-in to your site
5. If was not and thus your code redirected me to example.com/login
6. On the login page, the `template_redirect` hook ran and your code checked if I was logged-in to your site
7. ... and it went on and on like that without an ending..

Eventually, the browser gave up and thrown the error, "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

Because your code infinitely redirected me (or the current user) to example.com/login..

And actually, you've also incorrectly used [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/): `wp_redirect( 'example.com/login' )` — because that would actually redirect you to `https://example.com/example.com/login` and *not* `https://example.com/login` (assuming your WordPress URL uses `htpps`, i.e. the secure protocol).

So make sure you use a fully-qualified URL like `https://example.com/login` and not just `example.com/login`, or a relative path if you wanted to redirect to a page on your own site, but ensure the path is valid (i.e. it exists). :)

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that I had actually tried 'account' as the slug and that didn't work either so the fact that you used home_url('<dir>') seems to be what got it to work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I decided to revise it, and I hope it's more helpful to you. :)

Comment: PS: Sorry, I meant to type, `https` and not `htpps`.. also, the "without the slash" should actually be "without the trailing/ending slash".. (and I might revise my answer again to fix the typo)

Comment: Wow, you really went the extra miles. I definitely learned alot about hooks there!